# I am getting this error running my project using netbeans 8.2 and GlassFish Server 4.1.1

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I am getting this error running my project using `netbeans 8.2` and `GlassFish Server 4.1.1`

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> type Exception report
>
> messageInternal Server Error
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable
>   to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No
>   suitable driver found for jdbc/IFPWAFCAD" root cause
>
> javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource
>   invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc/IFPWAFCAD" note The full stack traces of the exception and its
>   root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition
>   4.1.1 logs.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1

Comment: there might be something wrong with `connection string`. Please update with code.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code on top of your jsp file

```
<% Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); %>
```

Comment: can you explain a little more @thili, why i should to use this?

Comment: To new instance of the com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class which will initialize the jdbc driver in your mysql.jar